# Use of several ontologies, have I to merge those?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege

I'm studying semantic web and I'd like to use different ontologies to enrich my raw sensor data. I'm using Protégé. 
Imagine I want to use concepts from three different ontologies (for instance SSN, CSSO and another), have I to merge (in Protege - Refactor-> Merge Ontologies) all ontologies in protege?
If I need to use only a part of these ontologies? (some ontologies are really big!)

I'm a newbie in this field and I would like to know the correct way to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to merge ontologies to refer them. You can use OWL imports directives instead.

It is possible to partition large ontologies if you only need to use part of them, but the best technique depends on what you plan to do, so it's not possible to recommend an approach at this point.

However, worrying about the size of ontologies at this point is premature optimization. First define your problem and a solution, then worry about performance issues - once they can be measured.